# How do I create a javascript if statement depending on my html input?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript. I'm trying to make a laser tag game to share with my friends. However, I want it to be like [Kahoot It](https://kahoot.it) where I can enter a game PIN to take you to the right game. However, I do not know how to tell my javascript which game I want to be taken to. Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
}

.logo {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 7%;
}

.codeinput {
  width: 20%;
  size: 30%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.codeinput:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.enterbutton {
  border: none;
  background-color: #018D94;
  padding: 1% 4%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.enterbutton:hover {
  background-color: #036266;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Laser Tag</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Laser Tag">
  <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Game PIN" class="codeinput" id="codeinput">
  <button type="button" name="button" class="enterbutton" onclick="enterfunc">ENTER</button>
</body>
<script src="js/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var codeinput = document.getElementById('codeinput').value;

  function enterfunc() {
    if (codeinput == '2147') {
      alert('Great! This works!');
    } else {
      alert('Hmm...something in your code is not right');
    }

  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `var codeinput = document.getElementById('codeinput').value;` is read on page load. It will not magically update the variable.... Move it inside of the function.....

Comment: `var codeinput = document.getElementById('codeinput').value;` – that would belong _into_ your function here, so that the _current_ value gets read, when the button gets clicked. Otherwise, you are only reading the value the field had at the time this line of code executed (and that was just _empty_ at this time.)

Comment: also use onclick="enterfunc()"  not just func name so that JS can execute that function code.

Comment: `if(document.getElementById('codeinput').value =='2147')` will give your desired output

Comment: You can also use `var codeinput = document.getElementById('codeinput');` to store the element itself, then use `if (codeinput.value == '2147')` to read the current value inside the function.

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: @mplungjan I do not understand why you want to do this. the issue is still not resolved, it was not caused by a typo, or it would have been spotted by now

Comment: typo-type. Move the line and it works and is Not reproducible. That is a minimum change that is NOT interesting to anyone else but you and you fixed it now, right?

Comment: Here: Fixed it here too: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/sf8hxpjt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to move `var codeinput = document.getElementById('codeinput').value;` into your function like this:

```
function enterfunc() {

  var codeinput = document.getElementById('codeinput').value;

  if (codeinput == '2147') {
    alert('Great! This works!');
  } else {
    alert('Hmm...something in your code is not right');
  }

}
```

This way, always the current input is read.

Also you have to call the function correctly in your HTML:

```
<button type="button" name="button" class="enterbutton" onclick="enterfunc()">ENTER</button>
```

Since `enterfunc()` is a function, you have to use the brackets inside the button tag.

Comment: `onclick="enterfunc"`

Comment: hi! but, when i put in the number 2147, i get the error message saying that something is not right. could you help me please?

Comment: @SiannaZewdie maybe you can try `if (codeinput == 2147)` without quotes?

Comment: Can you send a link? Because the JSFiddle above doesn't work...

Comment: It does work! You still did not move your variable declaration inside the function!! Look at my code. `var codeinput = document.getElementById('codeinput').value;` has to be **inside** `enterfunc()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222017/discussion-between-sianna-zewdie-and-deni-juric).